# Extending a functor up to homotopy

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, model-categories

Consider a functor between small categories $i:\mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ which is faithful, not full, and bijective on objects. Consider a functor $F:\mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{M}$ where $\mathcal{M}$ is a combinatorial simplicial model category such that there is no functor $\overline{F}:\mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{M}$ such that $\overline{F}.i = F$. Let $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$ be the homotopy category of $\mathcal{M}$. The composite functor $F':\mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{M} \to \mathrm{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$ can be extended to a functor $\overline{F'}:\mathcal{B} \to \mathrm{Ho}(\mathcal{M})$, i.e. such that $\overline{F'}.i = F'$.

> Are there similar situations in the mathematical literature which we
>   could help me to understand what to do ?

Comment: What's your goal here?

Comment: My goal would be to find a Quillen equivalence $\mathcal{M}\to \mathcal{N}$ such that the composite functor $\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{M}\to \mathcal{N}$ is extendable to a functor from $\mathcal{B}\to \mathcal{N}$. There is no canonical choice for $F'$. Maybe there is a way to encode all the possible choices. I would be interested in seeing how similar problems are treated in the literature.